# How to pass struct from c++ to function in c?

Tags: c++, c, struct

I have a C++ file which is like below:

```cpp
int myNum[10] = {10, 20, 20, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100};

struct rfid
{
    int AntennaID;
    char *tid;
};

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    AntennaID = myNum[i];

    struct rfid p1 = {AntennaID, tid};

    cout << "roll no : " << p1.AntennaID << endl;
    cout << "roll no : " << p1.tid << endl; 
    passInfo(*p1);
}
```

And I have a C file, which is like below:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void passInfo(*p1)
{
    printf("%s :: \n", *p1);
}
```

How to pass the structure which is framed in C++ to a function of C?

Comment: passInfo is a function which is in c file. Have used extern c to in c++ file to access the function.

Comment: `void passInfo(*p1) ` does this even compile? you did not specify type of `*p1`

Comment: No, its not. I dont know, how to achieve my result for this. I am not aware of c & c++ functionalities.

Comment: The question is unclear. You have a `.cpp` file and a `.h` file ? or `.cpp` and `.c`? What compiler?

Comment: Why do you want to call c function from cpp?

Comment: @TonyTannous, i have .cpp and .c and compiler is g++

Comment: what should this be? ***void passInfo(*p1)***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make a header that will compile for both C and C++.

```
// shared.h
typedef struct rfid_
{
    int AntennaID;
    char *tid;
} rfid;

#if defined __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
void passInfo(rfid *p1);
```

2. Implement your function in C.

```
// c.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "shared.h"

void passInfo(rfid *p1) 
{
    // whatever you want
}
```

3. Use your function in C++ by including the header.

```
// cpp.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "shared.h"

int test()
{
    int myNum[10] = {10, 20, 20, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100};

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        AntennaID = myNum[i];
        rfid p1 = {AntennaID, tid};
        cout << "roll no : " << p1.AntennaID << endl;
        cout << "roll no : " << p1.tid << endl;
        passInfo(&p1);
    }
}
```

Comment: In `c.c`, `void passInfo(rfid *p1)` needs to be `void passInfo(struct rfid *p1)`. The code would be cleaner if `shared.h` defined `typedef struct rfid rfid;` under C, instead of using 2 `#if`s on the `passInfo()` declaration.

Comment: `#if !defined __cplusplus
struct
#endif` is not needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I will modify the answer.

Comment: @KamilCuk yes, it is. Under C, struct type names must always be prefixed with `struct`. That is not needed in C++.

Comment: Not needed, but if you write it, nothing happens ; ) I meant just to leave `void passInfo(struct rfid *p1)`. I meant the `#if !defined __cplusplus` and `#endf` are not needed around `struct`.

Comment: @KamilCuk unlike C++, C *requires* `struct` in variable and parameter declarations of struct types. You can't omit it, unless you use a `typedef`.